# SatNav app with Audio Book app

Tags: applications, audio, navigation, audiobooks

I'm trying to find a satellite navigation app that works with an audiobook app such that I can listen to the audio book while navigating. When I get a navigation instruction I want the audio book to pause, then resume where it left off.

Google navigation just mutes every audio book player I've found (doesn't pause/resume), NDrive (preferred) just plays over the top of the audio book.

I've tried AudioBook player 2 (free) and MortPlayer (Audio Book).

Ideally I'd like to continue to use NDrive and find an audiobook player that works with it, but if that's not possible any combination of navigation / audiobook player would do.

<sup>In case it matters I'm in the UK and am using an HTC Wildfire (i.e. small screen resolution).</sup>

Comment: Have noticed a similar problem listening to podcasts. I'm sure the developers here could weigh in, but it seems to me that there should be some sort of "alert happening" intent that satnav directions and other immediate notifiers should broadcast when they speak, and player apps should be listening for it and pausing while the alert is happening.

Comment: @GAThrawn theoretically, that sounds correct, but I do not know (without looking up the api) if there is a broadcast that says "hey, I'm going to interrupt your audio, you should temporarily pause yours."  It may not exist. I'll take a look and see if I see anything...

Comment: Some standard broadcasts can be found here: http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/Intent.html I'm not seeing anything that sticks out to me to interrupt audio (other than perhaps for calls)

Comment: Thanks for doing the research, i wasn't sure where to look. I had feared there would be a reason why apps didn't pause. Looks like this is it! You'd think something like this would be in the API though!